# JSON.stringify changing properties

Tags: javascript, json, fabricjs

https://jsfiddle.net/6CDFr/229/

```
function testing() {
  foo = canvas.getObjects();
  bar = JSON.stringify(canvas.getObjects());
  console.log(foo);
  console.log(bar);
}
```

JSON.stringify() is altering the "x1","y1","x2" and "y2" properties, as detailed in my JSFiddle link above, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the (Mozilla) documentation for JSON.stringify (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior)

> **toJSON() behavior**
>
> If an object being stringified has a property named toJSON whose value
>   is a function, then the toJSON() method customizes JSON
>   stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, **the**
>   **value returned by the toJSON() method when called will be serialized**.
>   For example:

If you use the following, you should get similar values

```
function testing() {
    foo = canvas.getObjects()[0];
    bar = JSON.stringify(canvas.getObjects()[0]);
    console.log(foo.toJSON());
    console.log(bar);
}
```

or if you set the toJSON property to undefined (but I'm pretty sure that's going to play havoc with fabric.js unless you do it on a copy of the object - I've done it directly on the object below)

```
function testing() {
    foo = canvas.getObjects();
    bar = JSON.stringify(canvas.getObjects().map(function (o) {
        o.toJSON = undefined;
        return o
    }));
    console.log(foo);
    console.log(bar);
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, plus, I checked the map function documentation, and apparently it doesn't alter the original array(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
Thank you very much!